# How to detect which random did I chose from only one list with random.choice()?

Tags: python, random

How can I detect which random number has been chosen from the list?

```
list = [3, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 6]
random = random.choice(list)
print(random)
```

If random choice is 6, which 6 has been chosen from the list, how to know that?

Comment: You can't tell. If you need to know, pick a random index rather than a random list element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

```
import random

list = [3, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 6]

total = len(list)

target = random.randint(0, total)

print(list[target])
print("this is number " + str(target) + " on the list")
```

You can do this instead.

Output:

6
this is number 3 on the list

---

@Bamar noted that you actually want `target = random.randrange(0, total)` for the reasons explained.

Comment: This should be `randrange()`. `randint()` is inclusive so you could access outside the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the problem by indexing the original list and apply the random choice to it. In this particular case, with seeds' value equal to 26 and 27 to equal values are found but at different positions.

```
l = [3, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 6]

import random

#random.seed(26)
random.seed(27)

index, random_value = random.choice(list(enumerate(l)))

print(f'index: {index}, value: {random_value}')
```

Output

```
index: 7, value: 6   # seed 27
index: 3, value: 6   # seed 26
```